# Create/Update a commerce order using parameters passed via the url

Tags: commerce

Is it possible to Create/Update a commerce order using parameters passed via the url?

What options are out there to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is with a custom module. It should implement `hook_menu()` to accept as many parameters as you need, and invoke a callback that uses the Drupal Commerce API like in [this example](https://commerceguys.com/blog/creating-orders-drupal-commerce-api).

[EDIT] There are three modules that may help you do this if you don't want to create a custom module yourself:

1. [Rules link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link). It attaches a link to entity displays that triggers a rule. It passes the entity to the attached Rule
2. [Rules link event](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_linkevent). In some ways similar to Rules link, but from what I can tell, you can actually use the SKU (or other parameters) as an argument in the URL link, accessible to the Rule through a token `[path:last]` and so forth. [Main difference between Rules Link and Rules Link Event here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1365658).
3. [Commerce cart link](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_link). Similar to Rules link event, but works with ctools to create a token for the link, which increases security.

Comment: Ya that makes sense. I wonder if there is any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Please see edit answer. If you feel this adequately answers your question, please mark it as the correct answer. This helps future searchers for similar questions.